# How to add a video in the UI in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimageview, avfoundation

I want to be able to add a video (called "Logo-Animation4.mp4") into the UI in Swift, just like you can a UIImage in a UIImageView.

[image: UIImageView]

Right now, I've tried just putting an AVPlayer on the view, but it comes up with the default iOS AVPlayer, which contains the regular fullscreen, controls, and volume stuff that I don't want. I just want the video to play in the UI without any way to have the user interact with it.

I've thought about animating the video using a regular UIImageView's animation feature, but my video isn't that short, and it would be hard to get every single frame, and input it into the code.

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To achieve what you are asking, you'll need to use AVPlayerLayer

1. Add a UIView outlet

   ```
   @IBOutlet weak var videoView: UIView!
   ```
2. Import AVFoundation
3. Create player variables

   ```
   var player : AVPlayer!
   var avPlayerLayer : AVPlayerLayer!
   ```
4. Add the following code to your viewDidLoad

   ```
   guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Logo-Animation4", ofType:"mp4") else {
       debugPrint("Logo-Animation4.mp4 not found")
       return
   }
   player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
   avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
   avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resize

   videoView.layer.addSublayer(avPlayerLayer)
   player.play()
   ```
5. Add this method

   ```
   override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
       super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
       avPlayerLayer.frame = videoView.layer.bounds
   }
   ```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I'm not getting any errors or anything, and nothing is showing up in the view. I changed its color the gray so I could see it, and all I see is the gray, nothing at all with my video.

Comment: Have you added the mp4 file in your project?

Comment: Yes, it is on the sidebar in with the rest of the files, and I added it in the copy bundle resources.

Comment: And have you connected the IBOutlet to your storyboard as well?

Comment: Yes. I have the `@IBOutlet weak var videoView: UIView!` up at the top of my class.

Comment: override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        avPlayerLayer.frame = videoView.layer.bounds
    }

try adding this method as well